# Intellij build artifact configuration for spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, build

We're working in a Spring Boot project. Till now, I used to generate the jar file with IntelliJ *(community edition)* via Build Artifact, but since few days ago, the generated JAR is no longer having the normal structure of:

- /BOOT-INF
- /META-INF
- /org

but a "normal" java jar structure with all the packages at the root level.
Output is generated in the "*out*" folder as per my config (see below)

It is obvious that I changed something either because in my team the pom.xml has changed in some way I'm not able to find, or because I changed the IntelliJ config.

The most funny thing is that if I go to CTRL-E -> Maven -> (My Project) -> package, or alternatively I run from the command line "mvn package" this generates a perfectly well formed Spring Boot jar named xxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in the "*target*" directory

Note the difference between "*target*" and "*out*"

In my CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-S -> Artifact config I'm not aware of having changed anything:
The artifact entry, JAR -> From modules with dependencies, the output directory named "out", the manifest selected from the "resources" and not from the "java" dir, etc.

My pom.xml, of course has been modified several times lately, but still has the expected build section with:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

...
Honestly, I don't know where to look at, or even what to look for.
As per the mvn package working it is clearly not a code problem, but a config one, IMHO.

Any idea will be more than welcome.

**EDIT: Adding full pom.xml and versions**

- IntelliJ Community Edition 2020.3.1
- JDK v1.8
- Maven v3.6.3

  4.0.0
  pom

  test


  org.springframework.boot
  spring-boot-starter-parent
  2.1.4.RELEASE

  ```
       <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>test</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>test</name>
   <description>test</description>

   <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>  
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
           <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
           <version>4.6.0.201612231935-r</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
           <version>2.4</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
           <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <!-- For spring aspect oriented logging -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           <version>1.18.4</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.9.6</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
           <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
           <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
           <version>2.8.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
           <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
           <version>23.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-opera-driver</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
           <version>3.4.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
           <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
           <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
           <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
           <version>1.3</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
           <version>2.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
           <version>2.6</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
           <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
           <version>4.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.json</groupId>
           <artifactId>json</artifactId>
           <version>20180813</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
           <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
           <version>4.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
           <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
  ```

EDIT:
Tried a couple more things, without success

- Reinstall IntelliJ, including version 2020.3.2
- Reinstall Maven on my Ubuntu 20
- Change IntelliJ Maven config at File -> Settings -> Build... -> Build -> Maven -> Runner and forcing JDK 1.8
- Adding these lines to the pom.xml (news are only the maven entries)

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Exporting a jar file from the IDE is not reliable based on the problems you have described (changed configuration/version change etc.) always keep the configuration to create your result in your build tool for example Maven in your pom file. Why is there an output directory called `out`? In a Maven build the result will be put into `target` directory...

Comment: Thanks kmarbaise for your comment. I presume the response is the basic balance between doing everything "by hand" or letting the tools work for you. Before having to run the maven "by hand", I was a happy person using the build artifact provided by IntelliJ. I felt it more integrated with my IDE and practical, hence my willingness to have it back :)

Comment: Can you please show your full pom file ... ah btw. which Version of IDEA IntelliJ do you use? Which Maven version and which JDK version are you using?